# How to construct a WFS 2.0 GetCapabilities XML request to Geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, wfs, xml, ogc

I am trying to use WFS 2.0 specifically because it supports temporal filtering. My `GetCapabilities.xml` file is

```
<GetCapabilities
version="2.0"
service="WFS"
xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs
http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/2.0/wfs.xsd"/>
```

I use `curl` to make the request i.e.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/gml+xml;version=3.2" -d @GetCapabilities.xml http://ws-beta.int.unavco.org:9090/geoserver/wfs
```

But I receive the error:

```
<ows:ExceptionReport xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1 http://ws-beta.int.unavco.org:9090/geoserver/schemas/ows/1.1.0/owsAll.xsd">
  <ows:Exception exceptionCode="NoApplicableCode">
    <ows:ExceptionText>java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@44895b09
java.lang.ClassCastException@44895b09</ows:ExceptionText>
  </ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

I know the problem is almost certainly in my construction of the XML file because it works over HTTP:

```
http://my.geoserver.url/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetCapabilities
```

I seek a working version of `GetCapabilities.xml` for WFS 2.0.

I have also tried using GET rather than POST, i.e.

```
curl -X GET -H "Content-type: application/gml+xml;version=3.2" -d @GetCapabilities.xml http://ws-beta.int.unavco.org:9090/geoserver/wfs
```

I get a different error in this case:

```
<ows:ExceptionReport xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1 http://ws-beta.int.unavco.org:9090/geoserver/schemas/ows/1.1.0/owsAll.xsd">
  <ows:Exception exceptionCode="MissingParameterValue" locator="request">
    <ows:ExceptionText>Could not determine geoserver request from http request org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter$AdvancedDispatchHttpRequest@66acc6c5</ows:ExceptionText>
  </ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

Comment: Do you have some reason for not reading the GetCapabilities with curl and  GET?

Comment: No, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: You mean that `curl "http://my.geoserver.url/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetCapabilities"`does not work? Or with single quotes if you are on Linux?

Comment: What do mean with WFS 2.0 specific temporal filtering, that does not work with other versions?

Comment: in both cases I think the content-type should be text/xml while the accept type should be application/gml+xml;version=3.2 - I doubt it makes a difference though

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: The primary place to search information about how to use WFS standard is the standart itself.

Have a look at the current WFS 2.0.2 standard at http://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/09-025r2/09-025r2.html and from the section **B.7 GetCapabilities example** you can find this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<GetCapabilities
   service="WFS"
   version="2.0.2"
   xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0
                       http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/2.0/wfs.xsd"/>
```

I tested that request document with the demo request utility that comes with GeoServer and it did work. I had to remove the line `<?xml version="1.0" ?>"` I guess because the application is adding it automatically. Using version 2.0.2 that GeoServer does not support was not critical but GeoServer answered with the highest version that it supports, 2.0.0.

Then I saved the XML from the WFS standard as is into a file and used your curl command with my local GeoServer

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/gml+xml;version=3.2" -d @GetCapabilities.xml http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs
```

That worked as well.

Answer (score 0):

The 1.0.0 and 1.1.0 requests didn't include the version in the namespace, but 2.0.0 requires it (tested with GeoServer 2.10.1): xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0".